# Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ButtonState found

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm setting a number of environment variables at the App of my SwiftUI app and one of them cannot be found by the child views and I can't workout why!?!

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MentalMathSwiftUIApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var buttonState = ButtonState()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(buttonState)
        }
    }
}
```

The ButtonState

```
class ButtonState: ObservableObject{
    
    enum ButtonState: String {
        case STOPPED
        case ACTIVE
        case PAUSED
    }
    
    @Published var currentButtonState: ButtonState = .STOPPED
```

The MainView

```
struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var buttonState: ButtonState
    
    init(){
        var t = buttonState.currentButtonState  <- **Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ButtonState found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ButtonState may be missing as an ancestor of this view.**
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Mental Maths!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
            
            ContainerView()
            MainButtonView()
        }
    }
}
```

Do your best to ignore the pointless logic in the `init()` of `MainView` but why am I not be able to pull in the buttonState from the environment variable at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialiser is executed before the `.environmentObject` could be called to inject the `@EnvironmentObject`. This is why trying to access said environment object from the `init` causes a fatal error.

You should inject the object in the init instead of setting it as an `@EnvironmentObject` to avoid runtime crashes.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var buttonState: ButtonState
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Mental Maths!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
            
            ContainerView()
            MainButtonView()
        }
    }
}

@main
struct MentalMathSwiftUIApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var buttonState = ButtonState()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView(buttonState: buttonState)
        }
    }
}
```